# Android DatePicker setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have 2 android datepickers and I want to get the dayOfWeek in each date picker but I get only the initial calendar day even if I change it. How to set the clickListener? I would like to get the day of the week in dayOfWeek and dayOfWeek1 variables.

```
    dpTake=(DatePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dpTake);
    dpDelivery=(DatePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dpDelivery);


    Date dt = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);


    dpDelivery.updateDate(c.YEAR, c.MONTH, c.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    dt = c.getTime();
    dpTake.setMinDate(dt.getTime());

    CalendarView cv = dpTake.getCalendarView(); 
    long current = cv.getDate();
    cv.setDate(cv.getMaxDate(), false, true);
    cv.setDate(current, false, true);


    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
    dt = c.getTime();
    dpDelivery.setMinDate(dt.getTime());
    CalendarView cvDelivery = dpDelivery.getCalendarView();
    current = cvDelivery.getDate();
    cvDelivery.setDate(cv.getMaxDate(), false, true);
    cvDelivery.setDate(current, false, true);
    dayOfWeek1 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: I don't get your question. What exactly is the current behaviour and what behaviour do you want to achieve? I don't see a spinner in your code.

Comment: I am sorry. I have 2 datepicker spinners. When I choose date I would like to get the dayOfWeek (for e.g for Sunday the dayOfWeek=1 ). But in the dayOfWeek variable I keep only the initial value of the datepicker and I think I should have a listener but don't know how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                                }
                            },
                            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                    );
                    dpd.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#029789"));
                    dpd.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance());
                    dpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
```

Comment: Is there any error while testing. If any please share.

Comment: I had problems with some methods. Android studio did not recognize them. Also the dayOfWeek does not save the selected date - I don't know the reason. Finally setMinDate funtion will return the max year (2100) by default.